# How Angular client listen to Node.js onChange?

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack, mean

I have the following setup:

(1) Node.js server connects to another api via websocket.  This api provides an onChange behavior that can be listened to.

(2) Angular frontend calls api from Node.js server (which in turns call websocket api as stated in #1).

How can frontend be aware of the onChange behavior that the Node.js server is listening to?

Comment: You can use the EventSource feature and listen to an event which your node js server sent on the angular side. Here you can read more about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventSource. Go here for an example http://www.smartjava.org/content/html5-server-sent-events-angularjs-nodejs-and-expressjs.

Answer (score -1):

Use Emitter Service in Angular,whenever node server receive changes it should emit from node and angular should be able work on written logic